# Unquote and evaluate character vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function that takes arguments without quotes. It works fine.

```
iso_bin(modelingdata3, Default_Updated, Next.Scheduled.Payment.Amount)
```

When I am passing the above in other custom function, it is returning error.

```
myf <- function(df,y,x) {
x <- enquo(x)
y <- enquo(y)
return(iso_bin(df, !!y, !!x))
}

myf(modelingdata3, Default_Updated, Next.Scheduled.Payment.Amount)
```

Comment: Try curly-curly operator, `myf <- function(df,y,x) {
  return(iso_bin(df, {{y}}, {{x}}))
}`

Answer (score 1):

No reproducible example to test but you can try the curly-curly (`{{}}`) operator which was build to avoid using `enquo` and `!!`.

```
library(rlang)

myf <- function(df,y,x) { 
    return(iso_bin(df, {{y}}, {{x}})) 
}
```